# get the label through the foreign key

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

These are my table.

My tables are

User table

```
id Name Sex
1  bob   1
2  taro  1
3  can   2
```

Sex table

```
id  label
1   male
2   female
```

User.sex is foreign key of Sex.id

What I want to get is like this below

Name  Sex
bob   male
taro  female
can   female

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
SELECT a,id,a.sex
FROM UserBundle:User a)
```

it says

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 97 near 'sex': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression
```

I guess Identity could help this problem.
So I tried such as

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
SELECT a,id,IDENTITY(a.sex) AS sex
FROM UserBundle:User a)

$user = $query->getResult();
$user[0]['sex']  //
```

it shows '1'(id) but I wan to show the label name

please give some hint.

thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to accomplish this task in SQL is to use a subquery. Something to the effect of:

```
Select u.name s.label
From user u, sex s 
where s.ID in (Select sex
             from u
             where u.id = 1);
```

will get you any one user record with a labeled sex.
so you'll need to modify your prepared statement in such a way as to run a subquery.

For multiple records in the result set, you may consider phrasing your SQL statement using an inner join.

```
Select u.name s.label
from user u inner join sex s
on u.sex = s.id;
```

will get you a matched set of each user's name and the label for their gender.

It looks like you're using something like a scripting language prepared statement functionality (is that php?), so make sure to read over your language's syntax on properly setting up a prepared statement to avoid an injection attack from a malicious user.